# jest tests and pure js access dom elements failed

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Im trying to test my function which appends HTML element to the dom.
I get an error from the test in jest:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
 let parentElementVideo = document.getElementById('adContentSectionVideo'); parentElementVideo.appendChild(widget);
```

parentElementVideo = null

```
it('test dom creation', () => {
        document.body.innerText = '<div class="widget">' +
            '    <div class="adContentTitle">AD CONTENT</div>' +
            '    <div class="separator"></div>' +
            '    <div id="adContentSectionVideo"></div>' +
            '    <div class="adContentTitle">AD CONTENT</div>' +
            '    <div class="separator"></div>' +
            '    <div id="adContentSectionView1"></div>' +
            '    <div class="adContentTitle">AD CONTENT</div>' +
            '    <div class="separator"></div>' +
            '    <div id="adContentSectionView2"></div>' +
            '</div>'
        CreateAndDisplayWidgets.run([]);
}
```

as you can see I have added the 'parentElementVideo' to the dom... so it not supposed to be null

run function:

```
  let parentElementVideo = document.getElementById('adContentSectionVideo');
         
            parentElementVideo.appendChild(widget);
```

Comment: Have you done a console.log on parentElementVideo to make sure it's being set to what you expect?